# Is it possible to draw this without lifting the pen?

Tags: graph-theory

I have to program and find an algorithm to trace this truss for a school project

[image: I am trying to find the most efficient(without lifting) way to trace this.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not.  You have more than two odd nodes on your graph, meaning that it is not possible to do.

[Edited: You can do it if you allow yourself to trace over the same lines multiple times.]

Comment: Why not? Nothing says that the pen cannot pass again on an arc already written...

Comment: @user52227 Except for the starting and ending node you have to reach that node the same number of times as you leave it - so you must have an even number of edges to such a node.

Comment: @user52227 Yeah, that's why I put in the edit.

Comment: I didn't see it! In that case, the problem is interesting as finding an efficient optimal algorithm may not be easy.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that, and yes, I am not allowed to trace the same line multiple times. There are 16 lines, at this moment, I can trace 11 lines without lifting :P. But yeah , I think I have to find a way with the least lifts.

Comment: @AdamGluntz Do you have a source where you found this theory, or do you have a suggestion where to look. I want to include it in my research.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path